# gdata client authentication without a captcha

Tags: gdata-api

Is there any way to avoid the captcha sometimes required by ClientLogin when using the gdata api?

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try. Hopefully, it's a one time thing.
http://www.gmailhelp.com/recent-articles/unlocking-googles-gmail-captcha/